# Swift 3 [String: AnyObject] Expression was too complex Error

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8

```
func createAlmsBoxParams(_ benefactorModel: BenefactorInformationsModel) -> [String: AnyObject]{
    let general = General()
    let array = [
        "UserID": UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userID")! as AnyObject,
        "BenefactorMembersNo": benefactorModel.benefactorMembersNo as AnyObject,
        "Gender": "true" as AnyObject,
        "Firstname": benefactorModel.firstname as AnyObject,
        "Lastname": benefactorModel.lastname as AnyObject,
        "Alias": "Alias" as AnyObject,
        "IdentityNo": benefactorModel.identityNo as AnyObject,
        "PhoneNumber": benefactorModel.phoneNumber as AnyObject,
        "PhoneRegionCode": benefactorModel.phoneRegionCode as AnyObject,
        "PhoneCountryCode": benefactorModel.phoneCountryCode as AnyObject,
        "Email": benefactorModel.email as AnyObject,
        "Country": benefactorModel.country as AnyObject,
        "City": benefactorModel.city as AnyObject,
        "District": benefactorModel.district as AnyObject,
        "RefDescription": benefactorModel.refDescription as AnyObject,
        "Address": benefactorModel.address as AnyObject,
        "EntityID": UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "entityID")! as AnyObject,
        "EntityLevel": benefactorModel.entityLevel as AnyObject,
        "DateOfBirth": "19700101" as AnyObject,
        "Title": "Title" as AnyObject,
        "Division": general.UniqueID() as AnyObject,
        "Job": benefactorModel.job as AnyObject,
        "IsBusiness": benefactorModel.isBusiness as AnyObject,
        "Company": "Company" as AnyObject,
        "IsMarried": benefactorModel.isMarried as AnyObject,
        "Girl": 0 as AnyObject,
        "Boy": 0 as AnyObject,
        "Education": 28 as AnyObject,
        "How_To_Contact_Us": 29 as AnyObject,
        "Member_Type": 30 as AnyObject,
        "Member_Grup": "sample string 31" as AnyObject,
        "Member_Rank": 32 as AnyObject,
        "Coordinate": benefactorModel.coordinate as AnyObject,
        "Locked": true as AnyObject,
        "Canceled": true as AnyObject,
        "Deleted": true as AnyObject,
        "IsHaveAlmsBox": true as AnyObject,
        "fromWhere": 2 as AnyObject
    ]
    return array as [String: AnyObject]
}
```

How can I solve this problem in this array ? I tried many method

What I tried ->

> let array: [String: AnyObject] = ["": ... as String(or Int, Double ect.)]...
>
> func createAlmsBoxParams() -> [String: Any] ...
>
> I deleted "as AnyObject" near by all parameters ...

but didn't solve

Comment: Why to use an array of dictionaries and not a single dictionary?

Comment: Using `Any` instead of `AnyObject` would get rid of those ugly `as AnyObject` conversions

Comment: @MaxPevsner that's not an array, it's a plain dictionary

Comment: thank you guys that comments very helpfull for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it's not really an array, it's a dictionary.

Second, swift is having some difficulties handling huge literals like this. What you can do is define a `var` dictionary and put entries one by one:

```
var dictionary =  [String: Any]()
dictionary["key1"] = value1
dictionary["key2"] = value2
//...
```

Comment: thank you alex I' m trying now and I' ll  say response to you.

Comment: It would probably also work with `let dictionary: [String: Any] = ...`. The type annotation is what makes the performance difference.